# Does Diamond Spray bypass DR/Magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage-reduction

Does the spell [Diamond Spray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/diamond-spray) count as a magical weapon for the purposes of bypassing DR/Magic?

The spell states:

> These magical slivers are treated as adamantine and cold iron for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

The term "magical slivers" makes me think that they might count as magic for the purposes of DR, but the DR rules state:

> Some monsters are vulnerable to magic weapons. Any weapon with at least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls overcomes the damage reduction of these monsters.

Since the spell isn't a +1 or higher weapon, I'm unsure if they count for this purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, *Diamond Spray*'s Damage Doesn't Overcome DR X/Magic

The word *magic* there is nonmechanically descriptive; *diamond spray*'s damage overcomes DR as if it were adamantine and cold iron. If the damage were meant to overcome DR X/magic, the spell would instead say

> These magical slivers are treated as adamantine, cold iron, and magic for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

Or, maybe, like [mythic *chord of shards*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chord-of-shards), it would say the spell "bypasses all damage reduction."

**More on *Pathfinder* Damage Reduction**
While it says [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction) that "[s]pells, spell-like abilities, and energy attacks (even non-magical fire) ignore damage reduction," the [FAQ](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Damage-Reduction-Ex-or-Su-) clarifies by answering this question:

> **How does DR interact with magical effects that deal bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage?**
>
> Although the definition of Damage Reduction says "The creature takes normal damage from energy attacks (even non-magical ones), spells, spell-like abilities, and supernatural abilities," that's actually just referring to damage that isn't specifically called out as being of a particular type, such as fire damage or piercing damage. ... However, if a magical attack specifically mentions that it deals bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage, DR affects that damage normally, as if it were from a physical weapon.

Thus, if the spell [*diamond spray*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/diamond-spray) did *not* say the damage was slashing damage, it would *automatically* overcome DR as it's a spell. But because *diamond spray* specifies slashing damage *then* specifies adamantine and cold iron, *diamond spray* doesn't *also* overcome DR X/magic unless stated. The normal physical weapon, in this case, is treated as *just* adamantine and cold iron. Which is sad.