# STR Bonus to Telekinetic Fist

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

Do wizards apply their STR mod to the Transmutation school ability Telekinetic Fist?

"Telekinetic Fist (Sp): As a standard action you can strike with a telekinetic fist, targeting any foe within 30 feet as a ranged touch attack. The telekinetic fist deals 1d4 points of bludgeoning damage + 1 for every two wizard levels you possess. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Intelligence modifier."

Comment: Is the critical modifier just x2?

Comment: And does this count as a magical weapon for DR purposes?

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, an attack that deals damage has a threat range of 20 and deals ×2 damage on a critical hit. That second comment is answered (albeit indirectly) [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36803/8610).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

The ability details what damage it does (1d4 + level/2), and Str isn't included.

However, since it is a ranged touch attack, your Dex mod would be added to the attack roll.

Answer (score 4):

#### A [transmuter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/transmutation)'s *telekinetic fist* deals *only* 1d4 points of bludgeoning damage and +1 point of damage per 2 wizard levels

Because the [transmuter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/transmutation)'s [spell-like ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) *telekinetic fist* doesn't *say* that the wizard adds his Strength modifier to the damage the *telekinetic fist* deals, the wizard does *not* add his Strength modifier to the damage it deals. The description of the [Strength](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Strength-Str-) ability says, "You apply your character's Strength modifier to… [d]amage rolls when using a melee weapon or a thrown weapon, including a sling." A *telekinetic fist*, despite the slightly misleading name, isn't a melee or thrown weapon. However, a *telekinetic fist* still has a threat range of 20 and deals ×2 damage on a critical hit, and, because it's called out as bludgeoning damage, the *telekinetic fist* isn't considered a magic weapon for the purposes of bypassing DR according to this sidebar [FAQ](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Damage-Reduction-Ex-or-Su-).