# How does the spell Windy Escape work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am playing a sorcerer in Pathfinder and using the 1st level spell Windy Escape. The DM approved it. The problem I am having is how the spell works exactly.

As I understand it, all attacks from normal non-magical weapons or natural attacks will pass through the caster causing no damage. And, the caster ignores the first 10 points of damage from a magical weapon.

My DM recently read it again and is now reading it as DR 10/magic means that for all attacks I only ignore the first 10 points but take the rest of the damage. It does not matter if the attack comes from a magical weapon or not

So, my question is: **Does the spell Windy Escape provide complete immunity to nonmagical damage and 10 points resistance to attacks from magic weapons? Or, does the spell provide 10 point resistance to all attacks from magic weapons and non-magical weapons?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to d20pfsrd, [Windy Escape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/windy-escape/) grants the following:

> **You gain DR 10/magic** against this attack and are immune to any poison, sneak attacks, or critical hit effect from that attack.

Also according to d20pfsrd, the [Damage Reduction entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Damage-Reduction-Ex-or-Su-),

> The entry indicates the amount of damage ignored (usually 5 to 15 points) and the type of weapon that **negates the ability**.

It also says that:

> The creature takes normal damage from energy attacks (even nonmagical ones), spells, spell-like abilities, and supernatural abilities

So, **if you are attacked by**:

- an energy attack (even a nonmagical one)
- a spell
- a spell-like ability (Sp)
- a supernatural ability (Su)
- any attack with an entry matching your damage reduction entry

...then you are in trouble; **your DR doesn't work.** Otherwise (if not attacked by any of the aforementioned entities) it does work, and you subtract 10 from damage that would normally be applied against you.

In your case, it's [Magic Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/) that bypass DR. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/177330/30214) gives a more in-depth explanation of what Magic Weapons are.

Note that Windy Escape protects against *one* attack. If it deals only 6 points of damage, you don't save the rest 4 points of DR for future use: they are lost, and you have to cast the spell again to be protected against the attack.

Pathfinder wording may be a bit tricky sometimes, or more than a bit. When in doubt, the best option is usually rereading all of the related rules on SRD. Just read carefully a couple of times, and you will be good.
I have also fallen into your trap once, so don't worry.

Be careful, and good luck on your journey.

Comment: I edited your answer to have the important bits stand out a little bit. If you don't like how it looks now, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Ifusaso Thank for your edit, it is very good! I am not rolling it back! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Baskakov_Dmitriy and Ifusaso. This is exactly what I needed to understand. I was confused about the amount of damage taken. Thanks for taking the time to break this down for me. Its a new spell to both myself and my DM so I just needed clarification.

Comment: @jigglescaliente Please don't write "thank you" comments. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//rpg.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Role-playing Games way of saying thank you.

Comment: Yeah. DR/typed is weird because its a little counter-intuitive how its written and players usually don't get it. It makes a bit more sense when you get used to looking at commonly known creatures like [werewolves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/werewolf) (etc) with DR/silver or some [fey](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/brownie/) who have DR/cold iron. You can find it in the Defensive portion of the statblock.

Comment: @Ifusaso With fey one could think that it means "fey resist everything except normal steel weapons"

Comment: Absolutely if you're not aware that Cold Iron is a separate metal from what is typically used. Most modern fiction assumes that steel affects them the same, but in DnD 3.P, they specify that most weapons don't qualify; only ones that were made with the anti-magical Cold Iron process or ones that are so magical (+3 iirc) that they overcome natural resistance. That's why I opened with Lycanthropes lol

Comment: @Ifusaso The problem is not with *me*, but with a hypothetical player trying to understand that by intuition. Who could think that fey are either only vulnerable to "normal weapons" or completely ignore them (the DR is against Cold Iron!). *I* have at least read the DR rules. :)

Comment: Right, I wasn't trying to question or correct you. I was just blabbering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63119/discussion-between-baskakov-dmitriy-and-ifusaso).

Answer (score 6):

The game expects the reader to intuit that the spell [*windy escape*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/windy-escape/)  neither actually makes the caster briefly insubstantial nor provides DR 10/magic forevermore for the price of a 1st-level spell, but, instead, that the spell *windy escape* grants its caster DR 10/magic *only* against the one incoming attack that's being made against the caster *right now*. Future attacks are unaffected. (There's no reason, for instance, for a spell to have *Casting Time: 1 immediate action* if the spell's effect grants the caster a super power that lasts *the rest of the caster's life!* I mean, why not just cast such a spell when it was first learned?)

A *Duration* entry of *Duration: 1 enemy's attack* perhaps would've been clearer—or, at least, more accurate—than the *windy escape* spell's *Duration: Instantaneous.* Most of the time when a spell has a [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) of instantaneous, after the spell's cast, the spell's effect persists forevermore. For example, casting the spell [*fabricate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate) turns raw materials into finished goods forevermore, and the spell [*wall of iron*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-iron) conjures forth an iron wall that remains forevermore.

By the same token, casting the *windy escape* spell *should* forevermore grant the caster the ability to "respond to an attack by briefly becoming vaporous and insubstantial, allowing the attack to pass harmlessly through" the caster. Unfortunately, the *actual* effect of the *windy escape* spell isn't clear from the spell's description, the description combining fluff and crunch into a confusing whole. When the spell's description says, "You respond to *an attack* by briefly becoming vaporous and insubstantial, allowing *the attack* to pass harmlessly through you" (emphasis mine), the spell's describing the *circumstances* in which the spell can be cast, *not* the spell's *effect*. The spell's *actual* effect is described in the *next* sentence: "You gain DR 10/magic *against this attack* and are immune to any poison, sneak attacks, or critical hit effect *from that attack*" (emphasis mine).

The [DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Damage-Reduction-Ex-or-Su-) granted by the *windy escape* spell functions normally with some exceptions. The DR reduces the damage dealt by that lone attack by 10 points if the attack is made with a mundane weapon (like a typical longsword) or a typical natural weapon attack (like a [giraffe](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/herd-animal-giraffe/)'s slam) but does *not* reduce the damage dealt if the attack deals energy damage *or* [if the attack is magical in nature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36803/8610) *or* if the weapon used is a magical weapon (like a *+1 longsword* or a giraffe's slam affected by the spell [*magic fang*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang)).

However, even if the spell's DR *is* bypassed, the *windy escape* spell's caster remains immune to "any poison, sneak attacks, or critical hit effect from that attack," making the spell useful even if the the enemy rogue attacks the caster with her magical rapier, her sneak attack damage negated for that attack, the poison dripping from the blade briefly not a concern, and the possibility of that attack becoming a critical hit absent.

Comment: Are you not confusing *permament* with *instantaneous*? Yes, there are instantaneous effects that permanently do something (like cure spells), but a lot of instantaneous effects do something once and are done about it. The spell, being cast using an immediate action, can be used against an attack while it is not your turn, then the spell effect says that it works against *that attack* and that is the duration of the spell, one attack. If the character is attacked more than once, the next attack will not be reduced by the spell effect.

Comment: I am not saying that this answer is wrong, but the first two paragraphs seem unnecessarily complicated to follow and the reader might be even more confused if he isn't *that* familiar with the system.

Comment: @ShadowKras You know that I know the difference between instantaneous and permanent. The problem I think that the asker may be having is reading the spell's instantaneous duration as granting the caster forevermore (*not* permanently!) the ability to "respond to an attack by briefly becoming vaporous and insubstantial, allowing the attack to pass harmlessly through you," when *we* know—intuitively—that the spell's effect is only good for *one attack*. If you've a mo, reread the question with that concept in mind and reread my answer and see if it's still a mess. `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan As a beginner who is also confused about that "instantaneous permanent" stuff, I understood how it works (intuitively) the same moment I have read the description, and "instantaneous" I have understood as "cast when attacked, no time needed for it". But your answer is the thing that made me a bit confused.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I've reorganized this, and I hope that helps. Instantaneous isn't a casting time but a duration, and I'm guessing that— from the asker's boldfaced question—the instantaneous duration of *windy escape* has been misunderstood to be closer to that of a spell like *wall of iron* than a there-and-gone effect (like it should be) like the spell *scorching ray* or *cure light wounds*. (Previous comment's terrible typo corrected.)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! No issue with the time frame of the spells casting or the amount of time it lasts. I know it is kinda like a reflex action. And, that it only pertains to that one attack. But, you did also answer the question I needed. Which was about the actual damage taken from attacks from both magical weapons and non magical weapons. The wording on these spells can be a little confusing sometimes.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thanks for taking the time to break this one down for me.

Comment: @jigglescaliente *Absolutely* it can be confusing. I'm glad to've helped, and you're welcome.