# Does Gravity Bow serve to bypass DR/Magic?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, damage-reduction

Can the gravity bow spell serve as a way to bypass magic reduction? Does using the spell make the damage count as magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, it does not

While increased damage can certaibly help with penetrating through damage reduction, for a weapon to count as [magical](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/),  an enhancement bonus must be added to it: either permanently, via enchanting it with the [Craft Magic Arms&Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation/) feat, or temporarily, for example, with the Magic Weapon spell:

More information can be found [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction):

> Damage Reduction may be overcome by special materials, magic weapons (any weapon with a +1 or higher enhancement bonus, not counting the enhancement from masterwork quality)
>
> ...
>
> For example, DR 5/magic means that a creature takes 5 less points of damage from all weapons that are not magic

A resulting weapon, if it were, for example, a Longsword, would be called "*+1 Longsword*", where +1 is your new weapon's enhancement bonus. Note that this bonus is listed *before* the weapon's name: when reading bestiary entries, you will see that the numbers listed *after* the weapon are total calculated attack bonuses. For example, [Bralani Azata](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/azata/bralani/) can attack with her *+1 composite longbow* two times, her attack bonuses being +13 and +7. [Common Orcs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/orcs/orc/), though, **don't** possess *+5 falchions*, even though it's not hard to mistake this total calculated attack bonus for a magic weapon's enhancement bonus if you are not used to the format.